# Android: get latitude/longitude from pixel coordinate

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently developing an Android application that "emulates" a mouse (with pointer) on a map. I've implemented the pad, which is able to move the pointer (a simple little view) over the map layer. Now I need to create the addMarker feature. What I have is:

- (x,y) coords of pointer in pixels (or also in dip);
- the width and height map properties.

My question is: how can I calculate latitude/longitude of point been touched by pointer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it is a real map, you should be able to get a clicked position on it in GoogleMap

Comment: Hi @Eenvincible, thanks for your reply! Is an Android mapview, and I can't tap my device since I should use the pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
Projection myProjection = myMap.getProjection()
```

to get the Projection of the map: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getProjection()

> Returns a Projection object that you can use to convert between screen
>   coordinates and latitude/longitude coordinates.
>
> The Projection returned is a snapshot of the current projection, and
>   will not automatically update when the camera moves. As this operation
>   is expensive, you should get the projection only once per screen.
>   Google Maps uses the Mercator projection to create its maps from
>   geographic data and convert points on the map into geographic
>   coordinates.

And then:

```
LatLng markerPosition = myProjection.fromScreenLocation(pointerPosition);
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#fromScreenLocation(android.graphics.Point)

> Returns the geographic location that corresponds to a screen location.
>   The screen location is specified in screen pixels (not display pixels)
>   relative to the top left of the map (not the top left of the whole
>   screen).
>
> Parameters:
>      point  A Point on the screen in screen pixels.
>
> Returns: The
>   LatLng corresponding to the point on the screen, or null if the ray
>   through the given screen point does not intersect the ground plane
>   (this might be the case if the map is heavily tilted).

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! It has been my fault cause there was an error on my code that passes wrong points coordinates!